# Maximizing Multiplier Based on Precision in Python

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

Given the following equation:

```
x / y = z
```

Where the precision of `x` is 5 and the precision of `z` is 8, given the following values of `x`, `y`:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

x = Decimal('15.00000')
y = Decimal('81.63')
x_prec = 5
z_prec = 8


z_unrounded = x / y # 0.1837559720690922454979786843...
z = round(z_unrounded, z_prec) # 0.18375597
```

the value of `0.18375597` for `z` is produced, which when multiplied by `y` gives a value of `14.9999998311`.

Given the precision of x, we can "max" the value of `z` to `0.18375603`, since:

```py
z_max = Decimal('0.18375603')
x_unrounded = y * z_max  # 15.0000047289
x = round(x_unrounded, x_prec) # 15.00000
```

I know that I can find this `z_max` value in a loop:

```py
extra_z = Decimal('0.0')
min_z = Decimal('0.00000001')

while True:
    next_z = z + extra_z + min_z
    if round(y * next_z, x_prec) > x:
        break
                
    extra_z += min_z

extra_z # 0.00000006
max_z = z + extra_z # 0.18375603
```

But using this sort of method feels wrong, or at least that I'm missing some key insight about precision and `Decimal` values.

Is there a clearer or more algebraic way of calculating `max_z`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the precision of a product (or quotient) of two numbers is the minimum precision of the two factors (or of dividend and divisor).

- To a first approximation (pun intended), check out what Wikipedia says about [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Significant_figures&oldid=1144906661#Multiplication_and_division).
- For a fully general answer, look into the mathematical field of *error analysis*.

In your particular case, the precision of `x` is `5`, so any product/division involving `x` can't have higher precision than that. The number `0.18375` does seem to have a precision of `5`.

Being a calculated quantity, the precision of `z` of course depends on that of `y` as well; it would be `min(x_prec, y_prec)`, even if `z` nominally has a precision of `8`.

I agree with the other answerer that, once you know the allowable range for each of `x` and `y`, you can just calculate the corresponding range for `z` as `zMin = xMin/yMax` and `zMax = xMax/yMin` (easy in this case). For a fully general answer, error analysis is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about significant figures. Wiki has a lot of info on it.

If x=1.0 and y=1.0, which have both 2 significant numbers, and you want to find the maximum allowable range for z, then checking the limits for the number x will suffice. In this case the range is from 0.95 to 1.049999. These two values are the limits if x_prec = 2 and will both round to 1.0.

Comment: Any reason for 4 9's at the end of 1.049999 instead of say, 5?